# Is my FTP connection secure?

Tags: networking, security, ftp, sftp

First, I'm not sure to ask this question in StackOverflow cause it is for programming so SuperUser is more proper place I think.

My hosting provider said that the FTP feature is not secure (not FTPS nor SFTP) for the hosting packet that I bought (I'm using shared hosting).

(I don't really believe the CS because the previous answer about my previous question (about laravel in shared hosting) were answered wrong, she said It can't be done but after watching some videos I can make it work.)

First, I think that's right couse the url to connect to FTP is somethink like: `ftp://ftp.[mywebname].com`

But when I tried to connect via FTP client FileZilla,
the output from the console is

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxxxxx.com
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

And here's the certificate detail (The icon also said that it is encrypted) 
Here's the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Also, I tried to connect via FTP Client Cyberduck, It said that the connection is not secure and offer me the secure way even the certificate it said 'not trusted'. This option also show the first time I connected via FileZilla.

Comment: FTP by definition is not s secure protocol, passwords are even sent in clear text. With TLS enabled your using FTPS. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Security

Comment: It looks like it's an issue server side rather than anything you are doing

Comment: This connection is *very* secure, if you trust the certificate.

Comment: Personally I'd rather save myself the hassle and look for a better provider. If you have the chance, try out SFTP (file transfer over SSH) - it works great with Filezilla or Bitvise SSH client.

Comment: @Sebi Any reason in particular? This setup is perfectly fine. SFTP, on the other hand, tends to be very slow.

Comment: @DanielB so i need to ask them if this really their certificate? What should I send to them? The fingerprints ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... via FTP Client Cyberduck, It said that the connection is not secure

The server (real name and certificates hidden, but was is shown shows what happened with the real server) uses a self-signed certificate which also does not match the hostname:

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls ftp -connect ftp.example.com:21
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=server10.example.org/emailAddress=ssl@server10.example.org
   i:/CN=server10.example.org/emailAddress=ssl@server10.example.org
```

This kind of certificate can be used to secure a connection but only if the client knows which certificate to expect through another way, like if the provider told the client personally the fingerprint of the servers certificate and the client then verifies the fingerprint when connecting.

In all other cases use of such certificates is insecure since anybody can create such a certificate and do a man-in-the-middle attack.

> ```
> Status: Initializing TLS...
> Status: Verifying certificate...
> Status: TLS connection established
> ```

It looks like that "Verifying certificate..." is not actually done or the result discarded or that you trusted this certificate before.

Apart from that FTPS is insecure unless you enforce use of FTPS. If you simple trust your FTP client to use encryption (i.e. TLS) when available and to continue without encryption otherwise, then all a man in the middle has to do is to reject the `AUTH TLS` command which is used to create the TLS tunnel. If you instead enforce FTPS and if you verify the certificate then FTPS can be used in a secure way.

For more information I would recommend to better ask at security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Very helpful, so I just need to force the FTPS connection, I trust the certificate anyway.
and yes I trusted the certificate before and check the option not to show it again

Comment: @AltianoGerung _Why_ do you trust it? :) Did you confirm that it actually is a certificate from your hosting provider?

Comment: I'm not yet asked for confirmation but i will. But assuming that the certificate is made by a hacker, why would he do that? He could just take any data that he want.

Comment: @AltianoGerung: An attacker will probably include information into the certificate which look kind of legit to improve the chance that the victim will believe that  the certificate is valid. If the certificate is for "expected-site.example.org" you are probably more likely to accept it than if it would be for "hacker.example.org"

Comment: @AltianoGerung: apart from that - according to your question your hosting provider claims that FTPS is not included in your package. So either the provider is not aware of it's own setup or you got already hacked because an attacker can also make you feel save if it provides FTPS within the man-in-the-middle attack even though the original site does not use FTPS.

Comment: Should ask them again then. This time showing the fingerprints, isn't it?

Comment: @AltianoGerung: yes, verifying fingerprints is the correct way.

Answer (score 3):

I would venture to say that the server you are ftp'ing to is configured as described in this FileZilla wiki article.

https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTP_over_TLS

It will allow ftp over tls if the user opts on the client side.

Have you tried setting you ftp client, in your case "cyber duck", to use tls?  That wiki page explains how to configure some different clients.

Also, in the interest of brevity, you may want search your hosting support for: ftp over tls

Comment: I already ask them, but the CS said it is not FTPS, I don't really believe her because the previous answer about my previous question (about laravel in shared hosting) were answered wrong, she said It can't be done but after watching some videos I can make it work. So yeah, she maybe misunderstood my question.

Comment: If the host provider is saying they can't do it, I wouldn't trust TLS even if it is working.  Better to take their word when they answer in that manner. In fact if they are keep getting things wrong, I'd switch to a different hosting solution.

Comment: What if i ask them for the confirmation about the certificate? Last time i didn't show anything, just asked "is ftps or not?". And that before I knew about certificate details that show on my filezilla

Comment: From what you described and what Steffen Ullrich answered above, I think you have the best answer for a competent hosting provider.

My previous comment was mainly taking a position on the poor/incorrect support your hosting provider has given in the past.

Support for your hosting provider should have training to access good documentation for whoever is responding to you.

If they gave me inaccurate support in the past, I would not be confident in the support that I receive from them going forward. I wouldn't trust what they give for an answer. Especially when it comes to security.